# How to code checkbox validation with php

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

I am trying to validate the following checkboxes and output an error message for each field that isn't selected with php. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='Car' >I have a Car licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[0]' value='Motorcycle' >I have a Motorcycle licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[1]' value='Fishing' >I have a Fishing licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[2]' value='TV' >I have a TV licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[3]' value='Dog' >I have a Dog licence<br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the input tag add "required" this will produce what you need

Comment: how do I go checking if all input fields are filled in before proceeding to a 'thank you for logging in' page

Comment: You could use Javascript or PHP depending on what your requirements are, the basic Javascript "required" as suggested above should do the same thing  though, (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) should be able to help you out

Comment: ok thanks, but once say all the forms are filled in and check boxes are ticked, how do you echo out a 'thanks for the info' message per se? ie move onto a page saying the above?So that there's an outcome to all fields being correctly filled in

Comment: This should work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438722/thank-you-alert-upon-form-submission)